# How to create and save doc file using PHP and database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a program for online leave application.

After logging in the data is to be saved in a .doc file, which will be used afterwards. The .doc file is created using the following code:

```
$pdf_data = $pdf->Output('C:\wamp\www\finalproject\mywork\fpdf\lvapp.doc','F');
```

Using this code I am able to create .doc file, but I need to change the name of file each time and dynamically, i.e. according to the username of the user. The doc file should have the same name.

Comment: The name of the file is just a string. So you incorporate the username in the string. Why is that difficult?

Comment: (it's not clear what is "online leave application")

Comment: It's also not clear what do you want from a database. It's in your question's title and tags but you don't mention it in the question itself (speaking about files instead). Please clarify.

Comment: Also it seems that you are creating a PDF, not a DOC.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$pdf_data = $pdf->Output('C:\wamp\www\finalproject\mywork\fpdf\'.$user_name.'_'.date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").'.doc','F');
```